# NBG set theory and the axiom regularity

Tags: logic, set-theory

In E. Mendelson's book 'Introduction to Mathematical Logic' he develops **NBG** set theory.  I believe it's well-known enough that a description here is not needed.  Althought it could not hurt to summarise the main points:

- The objects of NBG are **classes** and sets are defined as classes which are members of another class,
- NBG is a **conservative extension** of ZF,
- NBG and ZF are **equiconsistent**.

When Mendelson formulates the axiom of regularity though he essentially states it as "Every **class** is well-founded".  Why does he not formulate it as "Every **set** is well-founded"?  They seem (unless I am mistaken) to be equivalent in $\mathbf{NBG}+\mathbf{AC}$ but I'm unsure otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, they are equivalent. Using the axiom of choice (in particular, dependent choice), you can show that the axiom of regularity holds if and only if there are no infinite descending sequences under the $\in$ relation (I can provide a proof if desired). If regularity did not hold for classes, then we would have a sequence of classes $$\ldots x_2\in x_1\in x_0$$ However, by Mendelson's definition of a set, all but $x_0$ are sets, so we have the sequence of sets $$\ldots x_3\in x_2\in x_1$$ which means regularity does not hold for sets. Thus, if all sets are well-founded, then all classes must be well-founded. I'm guessing he formulated the axiom of regularity in terms of classes simply because the axioms are meant to establish the properties of classes, and consequently, sets as well.

Edit: My original claim that the axiom regularity for classes is equivalent to the assertion that there are no infinite descending sequences, while true, does not follow directly from the axiom of dependent choice like I thought since dependent choice only applies to sets. So, here is another argument. (As a bonus, this one does not require any axiom of choice.)

Suppose all sets are well-founded and let $C$ be a nonempty class. Let $x\in C$. If $x\cap C=\emptyset$, then $C$ is well-founded. If $x\cap C\neq\emptyset$, then $TC(x)\cap C\neq\emptyset$ where $TC(x)$ denotes the transitive closure of $x$ (the fact that the transitive closure of $x$ exists and is a set is true in NBG without the axiom of regularity, as can be seen in my proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3429441/a-detailed-proof-for-the-existence-of-the-transitive-closure/3429442#3429442)). Since $TC(x)\cap C\subset TC(x)$ and $TC(x)$ is a set, so is $TC(x)\cap C$. So by assumption, there exists $y\in TC(x)\cap C$ such that $y\cap TC(x)\cap C=\emptyset$. Assume $z\in y\cap C$. Then, since $z\in y\in TC(x)$ and $TC(x)$ is transitive, $z\in TC(x)$ so that $z\in y\cap TC(x)\cap C$, a contradiction. So, $y\cap C=\emptyset$ and hence, $C$ is well-founded. Thus, all classes are well-founded if and only if all sets are well-founded.

Comment: I see, thanks.  So does the equivalence disappear if we do not at least have dependent choice?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I don't see a way to prove it without choice, so maybe.

Comment: What does choice have to do with this? Well-foundedness is about the existence of minimal elements...

Comment: @AsafKaragila I used choice in order the extract an infinite descending sequence from the assumption that there existed a class which is not well-founded (recall that a nonempty class is well-founded if one of its elements is disjoint from it). I cannot think of another method to prove this. Although now that I think more, axiom of choice may not have been enough. I may have really needed global choice.

Comment: @Anonymous I think you're trying to take a bulldozer to a rosebush haha (if I may quote my favourite professor) global choice I believe (but stand to be corrected) requires some sort of large cardinal axiom  or something

Comment: @AsafKaragila In NBG+AC well-foundedness of a class is equivalent to the non-existence of an infinite decreasing sequence in that class. Without AC this need not be the case since there is no unique way of picking the next term of the infinite sequence from previous ones. The same goes for ZF as well, if you replace "class" with "set".

Comment: @asafkaragila It might be worth mentioning that the non-existence of infinite decreasing $\in$-sequences has been called by some authors the "Axiom of Foundation" (AF) to distinguish it from the stronger (in ZF or NBG) AR.  That is to say, in NBG+AC or ZFC it holds that AR and AF are equivalent.

Comment: @Jean-Pierre, Anonymous: It might worth pointing out that I am well aware to the fact that well-foundedness is equivalent to the inexistence of decreasing sequences (this equivalence is in fact equivalent to DC). I'm just pointing out that AC, or decreasing sequences are not involved in the statement of regularity (i.e. the well-foundedness of $\in$). So I have no idea why you're bringing it up here repeatedly...

Comment: @Jean-Pierre: I have **never** heard anyone make this distinction before. Do you have some sources for this?

Comment: @AsafKaragila In the very same book I mentioned, "Introduction to Mathematical Logic", 6th edition by Elliot Mendelson on p. 286.  In fact he makes it an exercise to show $\textbf{NBG}\vdash\textbf{AC}\rightarrow(\textbf{AF}\rightarrow\textbf{AR})$.  We, of course, already have $\textbf{NBG}\vdash\textbf{AR}\rightarrow\textbf{AF}$.

Comment: @Jean-Pierre: Admittedly, I have never read Mendelson's book. I've did hear countless other logicians use the two terms completely interchangeably. I guess things must have changed since 1964...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Times have indeed changed.  My professor (James Rafter, if per chance you know him) uses NBG+AC rather than ZFC in his work, because he prefers proper classes (he's an algebraic logician so he encounters varieties and such) to be objects in the theory itself rather than constructs in the metalanguage.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I used choice in my proof, so that's why it got brought up. Unless you can see a way to prove this without choice, I don't know why you're complaining.

Comment: @Jean-PierredeVilliers You're right that global choice seems like a bulldozer here. The issue is that I claimed that if a class is not well-founded, then there exists an infinite descending sequence of classes under $\in$. With sets, this follows directly from dependent choice, but I realized that trying to use the same method for classes uses global choice. I think I might have found a proof for that claim that avoids global choice, but a couple of the details are still muddy.

Comment: @Anonymous The argument is that if $C$ is a nonempty class and $y\in C,$ then either $y$ is $\in$-minimal in $C$, in which case we're done, or $trcl(y)\cap C$ is a nonempty set whose $\in$-minimal element is necessarily $\in$-minimal in $C$ since $trcl(y)$ is transitive.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen That's exactly what I was thinking, but I'm just filling in some of the details before I make the edit.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen could you please write this out as an answer so I can mark it as approved.  Also, just to be sure, $trcly(y)$ Is the intersection of all transitive sets $x$ such that $y\subseteq x\in C$?  You are of course not obliged to but if you could add in things like why the transitive closure exists, even more so as a set and whatever else you might like e.g. that no $\mathbf{AC}$ (or $\mathbf{DC/CC}$ for that matter) was required unlike in our previous comments.  I thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: @Jean-PierredeVilliers I made an edit to my answer which builds on the argument spaceisdarkgreen mentioned. Note that $trcl(y)$ is the smallest transitive set that containing $y$. It is not the intersection of all transitive sets in $C$ containing $y$ since $C$ need not even contain any transitive sets. I also linked to a rigorous proof in my edit for the existence of the transitive closure. The proof I linked to does not use any axiom of choice or axiom of regularity, and is valid in the context of NBG.

Comment: @Jean-PierredeVilliers I think Anonymous has covered it in their edit. The $trcl(y)$ is just the smallest transitive set with $y$ as a subset, irrespective to being in $C,$ and it won't generally be in $C$ (and doesn't need to be for the argument to work).

Comment: @Anonymous apologies, I did not notice